# react-hot-typescript-webpack setup issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack, livereload

I'm using this template to get my project setup: https://github.com/wmaurer/react-hot-boilerplate-ts

When doing npm start i get the error (eventually):

```
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module build failed: TypeError: compiler.parseConfigFile is not a function
at ensureTypeScriptInstance (C:\Users\mslavsky\Desktop\react-hot-boilerplate-ts-master\node_modules\ts-loader\index.js:147:38)
at Object.loader (C:\Users\mslavsky\Desktop\react-hot-boilerplate-ts-
master\node_modules\ts-loader\index.js:365:14)
@ multi main
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Can anyone help please? I did npm install as well

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look this project: https://github.com/jquintozamora/react-typescript-webpack2-cssModules-postCSS

There you can see configuration for WebPack 2, React Hot Loader, TypeScript and React